# Velocity template not found but why?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, velocity

I am trying to do a hello world with Velocity Template Engine. Here is my code:

```
package biz.tugay.app;

/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 22/06/15 Time: 10:36 */

import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.context.Context;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloTest extends VelocityViewServlet {

    @Override
    protected Template handleRequest
            (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Context ctx) {
        Template template = null;
        try {
            ctx.put("name", "Velocity Test");
            template = Velocity.getTemplate("hello.vm");
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return template;
    }
}
```

I will get:

```
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'hello.vm' in any resource loader.
Exception caught: Unable to find resource 'hello.vm'
```

I have a **velocity.properties** file in WEB-INF:

```
resource.loader = class
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

and **hello.vm** if found under **WEB-INF/classes** folder that looks like:

```
hello $name
```

finally web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloTest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>biz.tugay.app.HelloTest</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>properties</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloTest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloTest</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried following [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13695976/983430)?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter I want to make things work with .properties file.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter is right - you error logs show missing 'hello.vm', that thread should help.

Comment: The last two sentences of that answer say: "See how first we tell VelocityEngine to look in the classpath. Without this it wouldn't know where to look."

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Is my answer the correct way to do it?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Is there a way to do this with init-params?

Comment: @KorayTugay: Looks right - it's been a while, but I remember it being a little finnicky ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks to @Amos I made it work like this:

```
Velocity.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");                             
Velocity.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
ctx.put("name", "Velocity Test");                                                                
template = Velocity.getTemplate("hello.vm");
```