# Let velocity find templates in war

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, velocity, resource-loading

I am using Velocity templates which I store in `src/main/webapp/templates`.

My Jersey-based REST service needs to find these templates. Locally in my Eclipse (with Sysdeo plugin), I used

```
p.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
p.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class",
    "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
```

to make Tomcat find the templates (which I got from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38812523/927493). Now when I deploy the war to a "real" Tomcat, the resources are *not* found (Unable to find resource 'templates/FreigabeNeu.vm')

I probably have to set the properties to something different, but I just don't find how I need to do it.

I checked that the `templates` directory indeed is copied to the main directory of the war.

Comment: Is `src/main/webapp/templates` actually in your classpath?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: Do you think your web application could load a class if you put it into that part of your WAR file? I'm trying to get you to think about what a `ClasspathResourceLoader` actually does.

Comment: I _really_ would like to know what ClasspathResourceLoader actually does and it would be great if you could point me in the right direction. By the way: The templates are not classes, but text files, but I do not know whether that matters.

Answer (score 2):

The `ClasspathResourceLoader` will load resources from the *classpath*, not just some arbitrary place within a WAR file. That means that if your templates are in `/webapp/templates` within your WAR file (or wherever) btu that path isn't in the *classpath*, then they will not be able to be found.

If this is a web application, then what you really want to use is [Velocity Tools's](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/) `WebappLoader` which uses the `ServletContext` to load files from the context itself. That is capable of reading files from virtually anywhere in the web application, even from WAR files, etc.

You might have to double-check to see what the structure of your WAR file – exactly where the `templates/` directory ends up – to make sure you have the base path correct. My guess is that they will end up under either `/templates` or `/webapp/templates`, but I suspect the former is more likely... the directory `webapp` is very likely to end up being the root of the WAR file, so `/templates` is probably correct.