# Using AWS Lambda to render email template with Velocity?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, velocity, email-templates

I have not found too much documentation on this.  Is this possible?

I tried setting up a local lambda function, inside the function I tried to initialize velocity engine.

When I run the lambda function I get an error saying resource not found for

```
Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("src/testTemplate.vm");
```

How can I reference a template here from another package or resource?  Would I need to use s3?  I would prefer to store the templates in a local code package Lambda has access to.
If I do this how do I reference a .vm template from another package in the velocityEngine.getTemplate function?

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to load the resource from the class loader. Take a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051413/unable-to-find-velocity-template-resources

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Comment: I tried this out but it doesn't seem to work in AWA lambda as those directories don't exist at runtime.